# Java android large file xml parse to json

Tags: java, android, json, xml

I have in file xml and is very large 12k lines and I want to parse this xml to JSON . I did this but it cut and Json resulet is less than xml . I think that this happend becouse 
The string has a limited character length and it exceeds the value. I have no idea how it could be done to work properly.

```
private InputStream readXMLFile() {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator  + "yourFolder";

        File folder = new File(path);
        if (!folder.exists())
            folder.mkdir();
        File file = new File(folder, "RM_7.xml");
        Log.e("exist" , file.exists() + " ");
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
             inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            byte[] data = read(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  inputStream;
    }
```

public byte[] read(File file) throws IOException {

```
ByteArrayOutputStream ous = null;
InputStream ios = null;
byte[] buffer;
try {
    buffer = new byte[4096];
    ous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ios = new FileInputStream(file);
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = ios.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        ous.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}finally {
    try {
        if (ous != null)
            ous.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    try {
        if (ios != null)
            ios.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

InputStream inputStream = ios;
String xml = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
JSON objJson = new XMLSerializer().read(xml);
writeToFile(objJson.toString());
try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(new String(buffer,"utf-8"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return ous.toByteArray();
```

}

This is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <DICTIONARIES>
        <BIN_TYPES>
            <BIN_TYPE id="40259091" description="POJ_1100" />
            <BIN_TYPE id="400181537" description="POJ_2500" />
            <BIN_TYPE id="651131896" description="POJ_7000" />
            <BIN_TYPE id="798636566" description="POJ_120" />
            <BIN_TYPE id="1320806807" description="POJ_660" />
            <BIN_TYPE id="1533220545" description="POJ_60" />
            <BIN_TYPE id="2072388553" description="POJ_240" />
            <BIN_TYPE id="2361832307" description="POJ_5000" />
            <BIN_TYPE id="3319806799" description="POJ_80" />
            <BIN_TYPE id="3369836500" description="POJ_10000" />
        </BIN_TYPES>
        <TRASH_TYPES>
            <TRASH_TYPE id="497" description="Zm" />
            <TRASH_TYPE id="498" description="pet" />
            <TRASH_TYPE id="499" description="szkło" />
            <TRASH_TYPE id="500" description="ziel" />
        </TRASH_TYPES>
        <BUILDING_TYPES>
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="91" description="ZAB_WIEL" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="93" description="DOM_JEDN" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="94" description="DZIAL_GAST" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="95" description="DZIAL_HAND" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="96" description="DZIAL_PROD" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="97" description="DZIAL_USLU" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="98" description="INNE" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="99" description="INNE1" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="100" description="NIEZIDENTYFIKOWANA" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="102" description="OGR_DZIALK" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="103" description="PRZED_ZLOB" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="104" description="PRZYCHOD" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="105" description="SZKOLA" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="107" description="SZPITAL" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="109" description="ZAB_JEDN" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="110" description="ZAB_WIEL1" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="111" description="KAMIEN" />
            <BUILDING_TYPE id="112" description="SKLEP1" />
        </BUILDING_TYPES>
        <SEGREGATION_TYPES>
            <SEGREGATION_TYPE id="2" description="N" />
            <SEGREGATION_TYPE id="3" description="T" />
        </SEGREGATION_TYPES>
    </DICTIONARIES>
</root>
```

Comment: looks like a task not for a mobile device. Why you want it to be converted to JSON at all? why can't you work with XML?

Comment: @VladMatvienko I try do this but I can not parse xml file to objects I edited my post and put a fragment from my xml file

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka Can you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [XmlPullParser](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) since as you said storing 12k lines in one `String` might get limited.

Here is an example from the docs:

```
 public class SimpleXmlPullApp
 {

     public static void main (String args[])
         throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
     {
         XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
         factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
         XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

         xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( "<foo>Hello World!</foo>" ) );
         int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
         while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
          if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
              System.out.println("Start document");
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
              System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
              System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
              System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
          }
          eventType = xpp.next();
         }
         System.out.println("End document");
     }
 }
```

And the developer guide has a step-to-step instruction on how to use it. [See here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)

Comment: Murat I added a fragment from my xml file I try do what you write but I can not do this ...

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka See the developer guide. There is a step by step tutorial.